# trying to combine multiple lines between two two patterns in the same file

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I am trying to combine multiple lines between two patterns into one line separated by spaces. However, I need to retain the text before and after the two patterns.

```
Input
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
PATTERN 1
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
PATTERN 2
Line 7
Line 8

Desired Output:
Line 1
Line 2    
Line 3
Line 4 Line 5 Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
```

I found many examples of combining multiple lines using sed, awk, and perl, but I cannot find an example of how to do this keeping the text before and after the PATTERN matches unchanged.  Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly do add your efforts in form of code on your question which is highly encouraged on SO.

Comment: Is you actual use just like that or do you have multiple matches? Possibility of overlapping matches?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how you are reading in the lines.  If you give me some more information about what you're trying to do I could give you a better answer.

If you're reading them one at a time, this will do it.

```
while (my $line = <HANDLE>) {
  if ($line =~ m/PATTERN1/) {
    my @collection;
    while (my $inner = <HANDLE>) {
      if ($inner =~ m/PATTERN2/) {
        last;
      }
      else {
        push @collection, $inner;
      }
    }
    chomp @collection;
    print "@collection\n";
  }
  else { print $line; }

}
```

If you have it all in a string and want to replace it in-place, use this regex.

```
$text =~ s{^PATTERN1$(.*?)^PATTERN2$}{ my $t = $1; $t =~ tr/\n/ /; $t; }smg;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is largely what Perl's "flip-flop" operator is for.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @collect;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  # If we're between our markers...
  if (/^PATTERN 1/ .. /^PATTERN 2/) {
    # At the start marker, empty the array
    if (/^PATTERN 1/) {
      @collect = ();
    # At the end marker, print the array
    } elsif (/^PATTERN 2/) {
      say join ' ', @collect;
    # Otherwise, push the line onto the array
    } else {
      push @collect, $_;
    }
  # Otherwise, just print the line
  } else {
    say;
  }
}

__DATA__
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
PATTERN 1
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
PATTERN 2
Line 7
Line 8
```

For ease of development, I'm reading from the `DATA` filehandle here. You'll want to change that to some filehandle that you've opened.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Cross.  To say I'm a novice would be too kind.  My data is in an external file.  When I run your script with the data in the file as you have it above, of course it works fine.  I put your script in a file called perl.pl, removing the lines from  "__DATA__" to the end of the file. I put the Data a separate file called test.txt.  I then typed the following:  perl perl.pl test.txt > test1.txt.  I got this error: Name "main::DATA" used only once: possible typo at perl.pl line 9.
readline() on unopened filehandle DATA at perl.pl line 9.

Comment: I figured it out.  Thank you very much to all